# How do you extract data using QUERY when a reference cell contains an Apostrophe?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

```
=QUERY('DK Salaries'!$1:$1000,
`"Select B, C where A='"&A184&"' 
And B contains'"&O184&"' 
And B contains'"&N184&"' 
And F='"&Q184&"'label B'', C''")
```

The cell O184 I am referencing contains an Apostrophe. The value is `"Da'Ron"`.  This is returning an `#VALUE!` error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2. PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "Ron" at line 1, column 44....
```

How can I edit this QUERY to accommodate a value with an Apostrophe?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
'"&O184&"'
```

Use

```
"""&O184&"""
```

(replace `'` by `""`)

## Reference

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/O4XN3Jvk0i4/5Fkd7XsvB8cJ